# what does the following call mean in C?

Tags: c, cortex-m

I am exploring an sdk and I came across the following set of statements.

```
uint32_t init_time = 0;
init_time = get_current_time_in_ms();
(void)init_time; // What does this statement do?
```

My first thought was that this is a NULL check of some sorts but I tried zero and non-zero value in a test C code doing something similar but response in both case was the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement does not do anything logically.

It is sometimes added to avoid warnings in compilers and Static Analysers for unused variables

Answer (score 4):

`(void) variable;` is usually used to avoid unused variable warnings.

It doesn't do anything but the SDK dev might left it there for future use.